# Pearson and Spearman correlation and the corresponding 95% and 99% confidence level in Matlab

Tags: matlab, correlation

if I have two series of data:
`a = [1 4 6 3 4 6 7 8];` 
`b [34 56 34 56 79 23 48 28];` Then i can find the spearman and pearson correlation coefficient respectively as: 
`RHO= corr(a',b','Type','Spearman');` 
for pearson correlation, i can use:
`r=corr2(a,b)`
  or

```
[R] = corr(a',b','Type','pearson')
```

what will be the confidence level (95% and 99%) both for pearson and spearman correlation. i need result as in the given example.
let,

```
pearson correlation r=0.76

spearman rank correlation r=0.65

95% confidence level=0.34

99% confidence level=0.42
```

Note: My values of correlation coefficients and confidence level are general, they are not for given 'a' and 'b' values above.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`corrcoef`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html) for that. For confidence interval of 95% write:

```
[R,~,RL,RU] = corrcoef(a.',b.')
```

And for other confidence intervals, add the alpha (CI = 100*(1-alpha)%):

```
[R,~,RL,RU] = corrcoef(a.',b.','alpha',0.01)
```

`RL` and `RU` are the lower and upper bounds, respectively,  of the correlation.

**EDIT:**

For spearman correlation confidence interval you need [fisher transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation), which is arctanh(r):

```
RHO = corr(a.',b.','Type','Spearman');
n = numel(a);
STE = 1/sqrt(n-3);
% here the input is 95% confidence interval, for 99% use 0.99:
CI = norminv(0.95); 
upper_bound = tanh(atanh(RHO)+CI*STE);
lower_bound = tanh(atanh(RHO)-CI*STE);
```

Comment: thanks bro, i know that the function                                                                               [R,~,RL,RU] = corrcoef(a.',b.','alpha',0.01) can give me the 99% confidence interval of pearson correlation coefficient but how to find the confidence interval of spearman correlation coefficient.thanks